# Get correct keyboard scan code for arrow keys

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, keyboard, pinvoke

I am trying to obtain keyboard scan codes from virtual key codes in a `Windows Forms` application using the `MapVirtualKey` Windows function. The declaration of the P/Invoke stuff is:

```
private const uint MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0;

[DllImport("user32.dll", 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, 
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, 
    EntryPoint = "MapVirtualKey", 
    SetLastError = true, 
    ThrowOnUnmappableChar = false)]
private static extern uint MapVirtualKey(
    uint uCode, 
    uint uMapType);
```

I have overridden the `OnPreviewKeyDown` method of my application main window class (derived from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`); in here I take the value of the `KeyCode` property of the given `PreviewKeyDownEventArgs` object and pass it to the `MapVirtualKey` method (I assume that the value is actually a virtual key code).

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    uint uCode = (uint)e.KeyCode;
    uint scanCode = MapVirtualKey(uCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    this.HandleScanCode(scanCode);

    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}
```

The problem is that I receive wrong scan codes for the arrow keys (I recieve scan codes for the num-pad arrow keys instead). For instance, if the up-arrow key is pressed, I expect the scan code to be 200 instead of 72.

Comment: Wait, where are you getting 200 from? The scancode for the up arrow key is 0x48 (decimal 72) regardless of whether you pressed the actual Up key or the number pad key. (The difference is that the former is prefixed with an 0xE0, which Windows turns into a bit in the wParam of the various low-level Windows API keyboard messages.) Windows always uses scancode set 1; 200 (0xC8) doesn't seem to be mapped to any scancode. Or am I missing something that says the upper bit should be set in this case?

Comment: @andlabs Have a look at this: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Key_codes

Comment: @Matze  I couldn't find these codes beyond this answer, but strangely enough they're used in GTAV.

Comment: `MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC_EX` mode should help you in this case, but unfortunately looks like it is broken. You need to handle `WM_KEYDOWN` if you need scan codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that this problem belongs to enhanced keyboards only. The `MapVirtualKey` method is agnostic to left- and right-hand key codes. This means, the key codes 38 `Up` and 104 `NumPad8` result in the same scan code because the `Up` key is an enhanced key.

I decided to intercept the `WM_KEYDOWN` message directly because the `lParam` argument of that message contains both the wanted scan code and a bit indicating whether the key is an enhanced key, or not. This solved my problem...

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            int lParam = m.LParam.ToInt32();
            int scanCode = (lParam >> 16) & 0x000000ff; // extract bit 16-23
            int ext = (lParam >> 24) & 0x00000001; // extract bit 24
            if (ext == 1) 
                scanCode += 128;

            this.HandleScanCode(scanCode);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If a key is an enhanced key the wanted scan code can be calculated by adding 128.

Comment: I tried this and was able to capture all sorts of messages but not WM_KEYDOWN or any of the other keyboard messages. I am running a C# WinForms app under Windows 10. Anything special I need to do to capture these messages?

Comment: This message is sent to the focused/selected window only; so make sure the window keeps the focus, or use a keyboard-hook instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx