# Convert WinForms KeyCode to USB-HID-KeyCode

Tags: c#, arduino, keyboard, hid, keycode

I built a circuit with Arduino Micro that sends Keyboard inputs to my Laptop. With a program on my Laptop I want to define what keyboard inputs should be simulated. To do that I try to record keycodes with the `TextBox.KeyDown();` event but the keycodes are not the same as the HID-keycodes for the Arduino. Is there any way to convert WinForms keycodes to HID keycodes (indepentent of different keyboard layouts and without libraries)? Here is the Arduino HID-Library with its keycodes: https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Keyboard/tree/master/src.

Comment: You can map keycodes to scancodes by P/Invoking `MapVirtualKeyEx()`. An example is provided in this question: [Get correct keyboard scan code for arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001179/get-correct-keyboard-scan-code-for-arrow-keys)

Comment: The ```MapVirtualKeyEx();``` method returns different keycode as in the Arduino keyboard library but I need the same keycodes.

Comment: You're right. I did not know that USB had it's own scancode specification, different from that of PS/2.